# Why does WhenAnyValue observable trigger on subscription?

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have the following dummy view model:

```
public class DummyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    internal DummyViewModel()
    {
        ItemChanged.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine());
    }

    public IObservable<string> ItemChanged
    {
        get { return this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Item).Select(s => s); }
    }

    private string _item;

    public string Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _item, value); }
    }
}
```

When I create a new instance of this class, the observable fires immediately on subscription, returning null (nothing is bound to Item).  This is causing a problem in my more advanced viewmodels where I have multiple observables that I need to chain together in different ways.  I've been using a combination of Skip and StartWith, but it's getting pretty complicated.  Can someone advise why this is happening and whether there is a different approach I should consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's just 'by design'.  `WhenAny` and friends always return the initial value.  This makes sense in most cases - for example, if you use `ToProperty` at the end, and you would usually want your property to have get the initial value.

Obviously I don't know the details of your app, but I've got two reasonably sized apps and can't think of a time I've needed to skip the initial value.

Internally, `WhenAny` delegates to `ObservableForProperty` and `ObservableForProperty` has a `skipInitial` argument.  So you could use that.  Or just `.Skip(1)`.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I've got objects which implement IEditableObject BeginEdit() needs to be called only when the user makes a change, but not before, hence the challenge with triggering on the initial value.  I'll keep using Skip(1) - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.